# JQuery reading URL won't read letter A

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to extract variables from the URL

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
return results[1] || 0;
}
```

This works great with numbers, but, when I try it on a string it stops at the letter A

Ajax call below

```
$.ajax({
        url: apiURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {page: page, user_name:$.urlParam('user')},
        success: onLoadData
    });
```

Example URL:

```
http://mypage.com/pages/gf_profile?user=DaveSmith&items=show
```

Firebug Inspector Shows (look at user_name variable)

```
GET http://mypage.com/wishAPIs/profileWLAllAPI.php?page=1&user_name=D 200 OK 253ms
```

Another Example URL:

```
http://mypage.com/pages/gf_profile?user=HelenMajor&items=show
```

Firebug Inspector Shows

```
GET http://mypage.com/wishAPIs/profileWLAllAPI.php?page=1&user_name=HelenM 200 OK 253ms
```

Example URL that is ok:

```
http://mypage.com/pages/gf_profile?user=MickBrown&items=show
```

Firebug Inspector Shows

```
GET http://mypage.com/wishAPIs/profileWLAllAPI.php?page=1&user_name=MickBrown 200 OK 202ms
```

This is very bizarre, any ideas?

Comment: If I'm not entirely mistaken, your regex means "*any* of the characters `? & a m p` or `;`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the regex to

```
var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(url);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q3cgD/3/)

Comment: Many thanks, appreciated, it does not like url so changed and this working fine now: var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);